# Load Large Number of JSON GZ Files into Bigquery

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a large number of gzip compressed JSON files in GCS that I wish to load into Bigquery. Unfortunately they are in JSON array rather than newlines format which Bigquery supports directly. What are some options I have to transform and load them into Bigquery?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages. Your question is premature. Rather than ask us to solve the problem, you need to research the problem, try writing code as a solution, then if there's a problem, ask a specific question about it.

Answer (score 2):

An option you may consider is to load these JSON files from GCS to BigQuery using a [Dataflow pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/beam-creating-a-pipeline). In Beam Python's [fileio](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html), you can specify the compression type and file suffix. You might find this [File Processing](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/file-processing/) tutorial useful.

Another option is to convert the JSON files to new delimited JSON files individually using this command:

```
cat input.json | jq -c '.[]' > output.json
```